# Python - print long string in terminal but stay at the beginning of the string

Tags: python, terminal

I am writing a script that runs in the terminal and that displays a (long) multiple line string. My problem is that, when the string is printed, the terminal automatically places the cursor at the end of the string.

The string being longer than the number of lines in the terminal, I only see the last 72 lines of my string (my terminal window has 72 lines), so it forces to scroll up to the beginning of the string every time I run that script, and it turns out to be pretty annoying.

Is there a way to go back to the beginning of the string once it's printed?

End of string, the cursor is at the bottom:
[image: End of string - the cursor is at the bottom]

Beginning of the string, ~200 lines above, where I want to be after the script runs:
[image: Beginning of string - where I want to be]

I thought of using [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html), but that seems to be overkill for what I am looking for.

Also, I'm on Mac OS and I don't particularly care about portability

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: I would just redirect the output to a file, and inspect that file at my leisure. Humongous output lines that fill up the complete terminal are probably not meant for quick inspection like this anyway.

Comment: Don't print all the lines; or pipe to a pager like `less` (or more portably `${PAGER-less}` if you want others to use it).

Answer (score 1):

While `curses` is the portable solution, try printing the sequence `ESC` `[` `H`. It will likely work on all of the terminals you care about.

```
print "\033[H"
```

Reference:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: I added `print '\033[H'` but it places the cursor at the top of the terminal window, not the beginning of the string.

Comment: I thought that's what you asked for "at the top of the terminal output". Can you elaborate in your question about precisely what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Re your comment you made on `Aug 28, 2015 at 1:51`:

I think what you are looking for is `printing` this escape code:

```
print("\033[F")
```